# Generalized graph-minor theorem?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, large-cardinals, order-theory, graph-minors

Consider the following generalized graph-minor theorem:

> **GM($κ,λ$)**: Given any collection $S$ of $κ$ simple undirected graphs each with less than $λ$ vertices, there are distinct graphs $G,H$ in $S$ such that $G$ embeds as a minor into $H$.

Then the Robertson-Seymour theorem is GM($\aleph_0,\aleph_0$). [Vopěnka's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vop%C4%9Bnka%27s_principle) is said to imply GM(∞,∞) where "∞" here denotes "proper class sized". I was hence wondering what is known about other cardinals $κ,λ$. It is obvious that GM($κ,λ$) is true if $κ > \sup_{μ<λ} 2^μ$. And [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/208347) states that GM($2^{\aleph_0},(2^{\aleph_0})^+$) is false. So my questions are:

> 1. What is known about the minimum $κ$ in terms of $λ$ such that GM($κ,λ$) is true? In particular, I am most curious about $λ = \aleph_1$, and I guess GM($\aleph_0,\aleph_1$) is false while GM($\aleph_1,\aleph_1$) is true.
> 2. Is GM($κ,κ$) known to be true or false for any particular $κ > \aleph_0$? Does Vopěnka's principle make a difference?

[Note: I edited to fix an error that was pointed out in the comments.]

Comment: I have a result saying that if $\kappa$ is an uncountable cardinal, then there are $2^\kappa$ graphs of size $\kappa$ none embeddable as a minor in any other. https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100072881

Comment: @PéterKomjáth: Your result implies GM($2^κ,κ^+$) is false for uncountable cardinal $κ$, and so GM($κ,κ$) is false for any successor cardinal $κ ≥ \aleph_2$, right? I'll have a look at your paper; somehow I couldn't find it via google. Any idea for $\aleph_1$ and uncountable limit cardinals? Thanks!

Comment: @user21820 Do you have a reference for Vopenka's principle being equivalent to $GM(\infty, \infty)$ ? It's true if 'graph minor' is replaced with 'subgraph' (which implies one direction of the equivalence), but how do you show the other direction?

Comment: @AdamP.Goucher: I just quoted wikipedia's claim, and don't actually know a reference.

Comment: @user21820 Where does Wikipedia make that claim? I did a Ctrl+F for 'minor' on that page to no avail.

Comment: @AdamP.Goucher: Sorry I must have misread wikipedia's "homomorphism" as "minor embedding", and when I replied your earlier comment I was in a hurry and didn't check. I'll edit to fix my question.